# Crontab not running php file with mysql query in it

Tags: php, ssh, cron

I have set a crontab to run every minute for a test. Everything is fine until I put some mysql query in the php file.

Working  srontab:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script/cront.php
```

Php File Content:

```
mail('email@gmail.com', 'Testing cron','Testing cron job');
```

Then it stops executing. I am logging in with Putty to login to SSH. I searched around and it may be an permission issue which I dont know how to check what permission I have.

Code stops cron:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bookings";
$result = $con->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {mail($row['email'], 'Testing cron','Testing cron job');}
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: Depending on your cron setup, you may need to add the username that you want the script to run as between the last * and the /usr/bin/php. Not sure if that's the case here, but I did find this when I was doing something similar - basically if you're editing /etc/crontab manually rather than using the helper/wrapper `crontab -e` you will probably need to include the usernames.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to add the username as I dont have a clue how to write the code

Answer (score 0):

Add this to see if there is any SQL errors which can breaks the execution.

```
$con = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pw');
if ($con->connect_errno > 0)
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $con->connect_error . ']');

if (!$result = $con->query($query)) // of course, it's more usefull with a complex query :-)
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {/* ... */}
```

And add logs to your cron as follows

`* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script/cront.php >> /var/log/myjob.log 2>&1`

Comment: how can i check the log?

Comment: Also, When I run the file on a browser, query returns the values ok.

Comment: Log are saved into /var/log/myjob.log.
Can you echo `$row['email']` and run the file on a browser to see if email is correct

Comment: Yes I can echo the email address. File works on a browser. Mysql connection is causing the problem somehow.